# Patching on a specific date each month - how?

Tags: 18.04, cron, schedule

I am looking to setup an environment where our Staging and Dev servers are patched in the 2nd week of a month - lets say Thursday.  Then 2 weeks later - again on Thursday, we patch production.  This is security and app updates.  We're using 18.04.  I've seen so many suggestions on line and I can tell someone a dozen ways this doesn't work...!  I'm still quite new with Linux and need some guidance on this.

Comment: Patch what in this case? Do you mean upgrade packages with `apt` with the latest security fixes? Also what do you mean by "app updates"?

Comment: simply to run apt update and apt upgrade - this would cover security and applications I believe?

Comment: You can easily run a `root` `cron` job every Thursday, and decide if it's the 2nd Thursday by checking the day number. The 2nd Thursday is between the 8th and the 15th. Read `/etc/crontab` carefully, the format is slightly different. Read `man date`. After your update, check if `/run/reboot*` exists, and reboot if so, with `shutdown -r now`. Read `man shutdown`.

Comment: The basic theory is pretty simple: 1) Disable Unattended Upgrades. 2) Mark your Calendar, and keep it clear on those Thursdays. Not because you will have real problems -- that's your learning time. 3) Update/Upgrade the non-production systems. 4) During the next two weeks, test and check logs. 5) Apply to production.

Comment: I am trying to do these updates around 2am - I've been doing them manually now for the past few months and I'm trying to learn the crontab syntax to do this automated now.

Comment: @waltinator - if in my crontab I specify 0 2 25-31 * 4 as my schedule time - It appears that I'm missing something - as this will run every day (25, 26, 27, etc) AND on Thursday.  I cannot figure out how to 'select' the last week (25-31) BUT ONLY run on 4 (Thursday) - is that possible in a cron job?

Comment: Rather than struggle with `crontab` syntax, run the script 25-31 and let the script decide if it's Thursday using `date "+%A"`. Read `man date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your `cron` job on every possible day, exit on non Thursdays,  and put

```
if [[ "$(date "+%a")" != "Thu" ]] ; then
  exit
fi
```

near the top of the script.